# Bot checking multiple links

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I made an anti-invite command, however, the bot doesn't delete the link that is being sent in the guild where the command is enabled. v12.2

```
if(message.content.includes(["https://discord.gg/", "https://discord.io/", "https://discord.me/"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `message.content` includes each possibility separately, as the method only accepts one string at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Could use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a callback which indexOf's to check, which is pretty short.

```
// mock
const message = {
  content: 'Come join my room https://discord.gg/1234'
}

//
const links = ["https://discord.gg/", "https://discord.io/", "https://discord.me/"]

//
if (links.some(el => message.content.indexOf(el) !== -1)) {
 // link/domain matched
}
```

There are other ways too do the same, like with simple regex match.